# Is it advised to replace the power supply of my computer after 4 years for fire safety reasons?

Tags: power-supply

My question may seem a bit stupid, but I'm asking the following seriously.
I have an FSP Hyper M 700 power supply that has been operating in my PC for four years. The PC is always on, 24/7.
I'm moving the PC to an apartment, and it is still needed to operate 24/7, without any human supervision. There is no fire protection system there either.
Is it advised for me to buy a brand new power supply for fire safety reasons? The power supply is not faulty or anything, I'm just cautious.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I wonder what the MTBF(ires) is for a PSU?

Comment: @MichaelFrank - The PSU has a 5-year warranty.  I would estimate the MTBF is around 5 years.

Comment: @John - I didn't actually submit an answer. I submitted a comment.  Since this question, as it's currently written cannot be answered (should not due to it being too broad), I went ahead and deleted my comment.

Comment: It is not possible to give a direct answer to this question. I have a Lenovo Commercial Workstation and it runs 24x7 and has done for 3 years. Since I revamped it with a 2 TB SSD drive, it runs just above room temperature.

I had a Lenovo Commercial Workstation before this that ran 24x7 for about 5 years no issue.

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Replace the words "power supply" with any AC-powered device and it would be essentially the same question and answer.  "Should I replace my electric alarm clock after 4 yrs for fire safety reasons?"  There's no direct relationship between age and fire risk, so there's no basis for people to answer one way or the other.

Comment: The comments and answer(s) seem to conflate unit failure with *"fire safety"*.  Typically a PSU failure does not create a *"fire safety"* problem, assuming you use a PSU that has UL, CSA, and other approvals that evaluate devices for potential safety, electrical shock, and fire hazards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, no. Modern PSUs are very robust. A well built PSU should last at least a decade, if not two, three, or even four.

The most common point of failure in PSUs are the capacitors. If a manufacturer is cutting costs, they often buy cheaper, lower quality capacitors. These cheap capacitors often have a lower lifespan. When these capacitors fail, they fail open, cutting the power. You hear a pop, which is the capacitor blowing. It is extremely rare for a capacitor to fail closed, which could potentially cause overheating and a fire.

It might not hurt to invest in a quality uninterruptible power supply (UPS) to provide clean power, as well as to keep things running during a power outage.

Comment: *"A well built PSU should last at least a decade, if not two, three, or even four. "* -- Not likely at all, since they are dust collectors.   *"capacitor to fail closed"* -- That makes no sense, do you mean shorted?  A short should blow the internal fuse, so there is no *"potentially ... overheating and a fire"* as you claim.

Comment: @sawdust I have no idea why you say not likely.  My Apple ][e is over 38 years old and still on the original PSU.  I have many other vintage computers that are nearly that old, all on the original power supplies.  As for dust collection, spray them with air if the are.   "That makes no sense" to you, maybe.  However, to electrical engineers it makes sense.  I could point you to several videos, but Im sure you can google for yourself.

Comment: Switches can *"close"*, but capacitors create short circuits.  If you like to use *"close"* over short, then you probably like condenser rather than capacitor?  FYI I have two EE degrees.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!